# How do I implement a cost function that requires all outputs at once

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a cost function that requires all outputs of a neural network (ie over some range of training time steps) order to calculate its cost.

An example of this is where the behaviour of the network against future training data will affect the cost. E.g. the network might be trained to drive a simulated car around a track, and the cost is the time to finish or time to crash.

What is the way to achieve this in tensorflow?

Comment: By all outputs, do you mean the output of every layer in the network or the combined outputs for different inputs for some time steps? You example seems to point at the latter.

Comment: @layog the latter

Comment: I regret asking this question as it's very broad. I've voted to close.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888935/how-to-train-a-model-when-the-derivative-is-not-known-and-a-batch-of-outputs-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approaches would be to use Recurrent Neural Networks (sequence data where you can compute a loss function at some or all of the sequence steps), or Reinforcement Learning where you have only a reward at some indeterminant point in the future (e.g. at the end of the course you get a better reward for being faster).

Here's a good tutorial on implementing RNNs in tensorflow:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/dynamic_rnn.ipynb

Here's an introduction to reinforcement learning that I found:

https://medium.com/@curiousily/getting-your-feet-rewarded-deep-reinforcement-learning-for-hackers-part-0-900ca5bb83e5

Both of these are types of models you might employ to solve your problem depending on how you want to structure your problem. Tensorflow is a generic math library that provides automatic differentiation and GPU support, you can build any of these models on top of tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks David, I still don't understand how to do reinforcement learning with tensorflow though.

Comment: Yeah, that's a whole book or course in its own right. Specific questions about it could be answered on SO, but learning how to implement it requires picking up a book, course, or at least a youtube video series. But hopefully this has given you some direction to look in.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll try to ask a better version of this question later.

Comment: I've tried to ask a better version here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888935/how-to-train-a-model-when-the-derivative-is-not-known-and-a-batch-of-outputs-is