# How to train a model when the derivative is not known and a batch of outputs is required to calculate cost?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to know how to train a model in `tensorflow` if the cost cannot be evaluated at every input. E.g. if my objective function tests whether some condition is met *half* of the time (with any deviation from this being penalised).

Previously I would write code similar to the following to define my cost function and backpropagation learner:

```
# Backward propagation
loss = tensorflow.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=yhat)
cost = tensorflow.reduce_mean(loss, name='cost')
updates = tensorflow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
```

Where `yhat` is a tensor producing some estimate of the output `y`, and `cost` is just the square of the difference between the *true* and *predicted* values.

However, what if my objective function could only be calculated once we have *all* inputs (or some batch of data), and the derivative wasn't known?

An example of this might be training a neural network to find a set of cartesian coordinates inside of some other function (e.g. inside the circle `x^2 + y^2 = r^2` for various `r`) 50% of the time. The space of correct and incorrect answers is not finite, and while the derivative of the cost with respect to the output cannot be calculated (making backpropagation impossible) the loss function itself is relatively simple to calculate.

```
def loss(yhat_all, inputs):
  for prediction, input in zip(yhat_all, inputs):
    correct += is_inside(prediction, input)

  return -abs(correct / len(inputs) - 0.5)
```

Obviously `loss` is not a valid tensor in this case, I just wrote it out in native python code to illustrate the problem. Given the above example, how would I define my `updates` tensor in this case? Obviously I can't use gradient descent, so I'll need to use a different optimiser, but I'm also at a loss how to even calculate the loss given that I can no longer use the normal `losses` tensors that run over each individual output in isolation.

Comment: I asked a bad version of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856872/how-do-i-implement-a-cost-function-that-requires-all-outputs-at-once and I'm trying to phrase it more concisely here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you can do is to define your own cost function over a *whole batch* instead of single inputs. Sticking with your circle example, you can do:

```
inside_bool = ( tf.square( X_pred ) + tf.square( Y_pred ) ) < tf.square( r )
inside_float = tf.cast( inside_bool, tf.float32 )
proportion_inside = tf.reduce_mean( inside_float )
loss = -tf.abs( proportion_inside - 0.5 )
```

Another question is what the input to such a network would be. I'd suggest you just start with a random tensor. (Basically, build a generative network.)

If your loss function is not derivable, it will be hard to train. So I'd suggest replace the non-derivable parts with derivable approximates. Most importantly, the inside-outside boolean could be a large root of the distance from the perimeter instead (maintaining sign.) Taking a large root approaches it to one. (Raising to power 0 would be the sign basically.) You can also add a regularizer that likes values around one and negative one. (This would ruin the distribution of your coordinates, however, if that's a factor.)

`tf.abs()` is not such a big problem, that's basically L1 regularization.
So with all that, an idea could be (untested code):

```
dist_from_perimeter = ( tf.square( X_pred ) + tf.square( Y_pred ) ) - tf.square( r )
dist_loss = tf.sign( dist_from_perimeter ) * tf.pow( tf.abs( dist_from_perimeter ), 0.2 ) # 0.2 for 5th root
inside = tf.reduce_mean( dist_loss ) # 0-based now!
loss = -tf.abs( inside )
```

This would force all the points on the perimeter, but the gradient will grow really large around the perimeter, so it's not likely to be able to stay there. They will oscillate inside-outside, but once the proportion settles down, they won't move much. (Or so I think... :) )

If you have things other than a circle, then you have to come up with a reasonably easily calculable distance metric that would put close to equal pressure on both X and Y coordinates.

Hope all this helped!

Wrote working code for this, albeit didn't investigate the internals of the generated results:

```
import tensorflow as tf

r = 1.0

rnd = tf.random_uniform( shape = ( 100, 50 ), dtype = tf.float32, minval = 0.0, maxval = 1.0 )

l1 = tf.layers.dense( rnd, 50, activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss )
l2 = tf.layers.dense( l1, 50, activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss )
l3 = tf.layers.dense( l2, 50, activation = None, kernel_regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss )
X_pred = tf.layers.dense( l3, 1, activation = None, kernel_regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss )
Y_pred = tf.layers.dense( l3, 1, activation = None, kernel_regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss )

dist_from_perimeter = ( tf.square( X_pred ) + tf.square( Y_pred ) ) - tf.square( r )
dist_loss = tf.sign( dist_from_perimeter ) * tf.pow( tf.abs( dist_from_perimeter ), 0.5 ) # 0.5 for square root
inside = tf.reduce_mean( dist_loss ) # 0-based now!
loss = tf.abs( inside )

inside_binary = tf.sign(tf.sign( dist_from_perimeter ) + 1 )
prop = tf.reduce_mean( inside_binary )

global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer( 0.0001 ).minimize( loss )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for step in xrange( 100000 ):
        _, loss_value, prop_val = sess.run( [ updates, loss, prop ] )
        if 0 == step % 2000:
            print( "Step {}, loss {:.6f}, proportion inside: {:.4f}". format( step, loss_value, prop_val ) )
```

Output:

> Step 0, loss 0.963431, proportion inside: 0.0000
>   Step 2000, loss 0.012302, proportion inside: 0.4900
>   Step 4000, loss 0.044224, proportion inside: 0.5300
>   Step 6000, loss 0.055603, proportion inside: 0.5400
>   Step 8000, loss 0.001739, proportion inside: 0.4100
>   Step 10000, loss 0.136604, proportion inside: 0.5900
>   Step 12000, loss 0.028738, proportion inside: 0.4600
>   Step 14000, loss 0.089664, proportion inside: 0.4100
>   Step 16000, loss 0.035139, proportion inside: 0.4900
>   Step 18000, loss 0.021432, proportion inside: 0.5100
>   Step 20000, loss 0.008821, proportion inside: 0.4600
>   Step 22000, loss 0.079573, proportion inside: 0.5500
>   Step 24000, loss 0.145942, proportion inside: 0.3700
>   Step 26000, loss 0.009984, proportion inside: 0.4700
>   Step 28000, loss 0.010401, proportion inside: 0.4700
>   Step 30000, loss 0.077145, proportion inside: 0.4000
>   Step 32000, loss 0.029588, proportion inside: 0.5300
>   Step 34000, loss 0.032815, proportion inside: 0.5100
>   Step 36000, loss 0.081417, proportion inside: 0.4000
>   Step 38000, loss 0.079384, proportion inside: 0.3900
>   Step 40000, loss 0.040977, proportion inside: 0.5500
>   Step 42000, loss 0.095768, proportion inside: 0.5900
>   Step 44000, loss 0.012109, proportion inside: 0.5300
>   Step 46000, loss 0.064089, proportion inside: 0.4200
>   Step 48000, loss 0.001401, proportion inside: 0.4700
>   Step 50000, loss 0.024378, proportion inside: 0.5400
>   Step 52000, loss 0.037057, proportion inside: 0.4900
>   Step 54000, loss 0.004553, proportion inside: 0.4800
>   Step 56000, loss 0.097677, proportion inside: 0.4000
>   Step 58000, loss 0.060175, proportion inside: 0.5300
>   Step 60000, loss 0.008686, proportion inside: 0.4800
>   Step 62000, loss 0.077828, proportion inside: 0.3600
>   Step 64000, loss 0.000750, proportion inside: 0.4600
>   Step 66000, loss 0.071392, proportion inside: 0.5700
>   Step 68000, loss 0.066447, proportion inside: 0.5600
>   Step 70000, loss 0.057511, proportion inside: 0.5600
>   Step 72000, loss 0.008800, proportion inside: 0.5400
>   Step 74000, loss 0.000322, proportion inside: 0.5200
>   Step 76000, loss 0.002286, proportion inside: 0.4700
>   Step 78000, loss 0.008778, proportion inside: 0.4900
>   Step 80000, loss 0.044092, proportion inside: 0.4500
>   Step 82000, loss 0.018876, proportion inside: 0.4600
>   Step 84000, loss 0.108120, proportion inside: 0.3500
>   Step 86000, loss 0.054647, proportion inside: 0.5600
>   Step 88000, loss 0.024990, proportion inside: 0.4600
>   Step 90000, loss 0.030924, proportion inside: 0.4700
>   Step 92000, loss 0.021789, proportion inside: 0.5100
>   Step 94000, loss 0.066370, proportion inside: 0.5600
>   Step 96000, loss 0.057060, proportion inside: 0.4100
>   Step 98000, loss 0.030641, proportion inside: 0.5200

Comment: Thanks Peter, this is helpful. In my real-world example I don't have the luxury of an "ideal" value though, so the derivative solution that you found won't work for me. How would this work if there is no derivative (e.g. we weighted all values _inside_ the circle equally?). Is there a genetic algorithm optimiser?

Comment: Generally non-differentiable cost functions are dealt with by approximating them with differentiable ones. [Nondifferentiable Optimization](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Nondifferentiable_Optimization) For you particular problem, you might want to forgo neural networks all together, and just come up with a formula to create random numbers for the circle. Generate a random angle and a distance (polar coordinates) in a way so that the cumulative distance probability distribution is 0.5 at 1 (radius of circle.)